# How to use mod_rewrite in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Before I am going mad, I need some help with `mod_rewrite` in htaccess.

I want to rewrite the following url as follows:

- `www.domain.com/reviews` or `www.domain.com/reviews/` -> stay as is
- `www.domain.com/reviews/(one char or number)` or `www.domain.com/reviews/(one char or number)/` -> stay as is
- `www.domain.com/reviews/(string)` or `www.domain.com/reviews/(sting)/`
  -> 301 redirect to `www.domain.com/(sting)/`

How to proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.{2,})/?$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```